# Java: Object pooling and hash sets

Tags: java, garbage-collection, duplicates, set, pooling

lets assume following class...

```
class Foo {

  private Bar1 bar1;
  private Bar2 bar2;

  // many other fields

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Foo foo = (Foo) o;
    if (!bar1.equals(foo.getBar1()) return false;
    if (!bar2.equals(foo.getBar2()) return false;
    // etc...
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int result = bar1.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + bar2.hashCode();
    // etc...
  }

  // setters & getters follow...
}
```

Thousands of Foo instances per minute are created, processed and consequently recycled in a pool. The workflow is following:

```
Set<Foo> foos = new THashSet<>();
while (there-is-data) {

  String serializedDataFromApi = api.getData();
  Set<Foo> buffer = pool.deserializeAndCreate(serializedDataFromApi);
  foos.addAll(buffer);
}

processor.process(foos);
pool.recycle(foos);
```

Problem is that there can be duplicate foo objects (with same values) among different buffers. These are materialized as different instances of Foo, however they are considered equal at the moment of calling foos.addAll(buffer).

**My questions are:**

- What happened with those "duplicate" instances?
- Are they "lost" and garbage collected?
- If I wanted to keep those instances available in pool, what would be the most effective way to test for duplicates before inserting using addAll and recycling instances?

Comment: Just curious - why do you need all of this? If instances of `Foo` are short-living then these will not leave young space so will be collected very quickly. Your approach guarantees these will be moved to eden space sooner or later. When you later re-use these and modify then it will mark whole region dirty. 

I suggest you do proper testing of this pooling. If you write (or wrote) microbenchmark then double-check it tests what you will have later - objects sit in eden space and are modified from time to time.

Comment: When you don’t want duplicates to be removed, just use a `List`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happened with those "duplicate" instances?
>   Are they "lost" and garbage collected?

Yes, these will be eligible for GC immediately after current iteration of `while (there-is-data)` is finished

> If I wanted to keep those instances available in pool, what would be the most effective way to test for duplicates before inserting using addAll and recycling instances?

`Set.add` returns `true` if element is inserted and `false` if it is duplicate. So you can replace `addAll` with

```
for (Foo f : buffer) {
  if (!foos.add(f)) {
    // handle duplicate
  }
}
```

There will be no performance hit because `addAll` does the same - iterates and adds one by one.

Comment: Thank you Alexander, this is exactly what I wanted. But also thank you very much for your suggestion with pool testing. I'll do that.